# deployment fails with Passenger over Nginx falsely 'apparently not running'

Tags: nginx, passenger

A deployment fails with the following message:

```
Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
[...]
• You customized Nginx's  passenger_instance_registry_dir option  
• The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.
[...]
DEBUG [25d4f5b4]    *** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.7OMaC6P
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.7OMaC6P/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.0bmUABH
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.0bmUABH/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.n1oLEes
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.n1oLEes/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.RXBYda3
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.RXBYda3/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.TrAwTXq
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.TrAwTXq/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.vZaExdN
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.vZaExdN/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.dqTKpv1
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.dqTKpv1/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.hh2TxgL
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.hh2TxgL/.
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /tmp/passenger.rjowwmi
    Warning: Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chown - /tmp/passenger.rjowwmi/.
```

`passenger-status` runs. However two pids are shown

```
  App root: /home/deploy/margin/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 110639   Sessions: 0       Processed: 46      Uptime: 12h 29m 50s
    CPU: 1%      Memory  : 409M    Last used: 2m 50s
  * PID: 141836   Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 2m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 17M     Last used: 2m 46s ago
```

Installation occured via these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-passenger

if [ ! -f /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-passenger.conf ]; then sudo ln -s /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-passenger.load /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-passenger.conf ; fi

sudo ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf
```

the conf file has

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

While there is [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#note-regarding-command-line-tools) on this matter, it does not cover a gap in understanding - and thus does not mitigate risk.  Namely:
•  rather, is not a question of all these stale instances which is gumming up the works? How to get rid of properly?
•  uncertainty as to whether passenger standalone or nginx variant is running - how to verify?
•  there is no recollection of ever touching passenger_instance_registry_dir
•  if a system background service has been run to change the instance directory, how can one verify?
•  what is good practice for eventually setting and instance directory?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Not to my satisfaction.  Operationally, yes: both PIDs were deleted and the server re-started.  In terms of understanding, zero.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I restarted nginx and it seems to have fixed it.